# Understand AWS RDS Multi-AZ Sync Replication

Tags: replication, aws

[Multi-AZ AWS RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZSingleStandby.html) docs state:

[image]

1. What is “synchronous block level replication?”
2. Given that this replication is at the disk level, not DB proper, is this form as reliable as DB replication?

Comment: Was it really easier to post the screenshot vs. copying the text? [Text is way better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I will do next time. I was on mobile so easier to send a picture. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is “synchronous block level replication?”

Every [disk block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)) written on the primary server is copied to the standby(s), and the write is not acknowledged on the primary until it's acknowledged on all standbys.

> Given that this replication is at the disk level, not DB proper, is this form as reliable as DB replication?

It's neither more or less reliable than [any of the multitude of types of] "DB replication"; the reliability entirely depends on the specific implementation of the underlying principle.